# MYSQL PHP PDO - Adding WHERE PlaceHolder Clauses on the fly

Tags: php, mysql, select, pdo

I need to insert a MySQL WHERE Condition as a placeholder in PDO. The condition depends on your preference of gender (social site) - below creates to WHERE condition code:

```
    if($_SESSION['interestedMales'] && $_SESSION['interestedFemales']) {
        return '(a.profile_gender=0 OR a.profile_gender=1)';
    }elseif($_SESSION['interestedMales']) {
        return '(a.profile_gender=1)';
    }elseif($_SESSION['interestedFemales']) {
        return '(a.profile_gender=0)';
    }else{
  return '(a.profile_gender='.$_SESSION['gender'].')';
    }
```

returns into variable - $pdoGenderCondition

Next I'm adding this to a PHP PDO statement:

```
    $sql='SELECT a.userinfo
                FROM login AS a
                WHERE a.photoidvisible=1  AND ? LIMIT 9;';
    echo $sql;
    $pds=$database_users->pdo->prepare($sql); $pds->execute(array($pdoGenderCondition)); $rows=$pds->fetchAll();
```

where I run this I get no results.

If I directly put the $pdoGenderCondition into the PHP PDO statement it works.

I'm guessing you can't put this kind of WHERE clause on the fly into PDO but I believe I've seen it before.

I could use multiple SELECT statements but would rather use one.

Any advise would be greatly appreciated.

thx
Adam

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You cannot do that.

Placeholders can only be used for passing parameters. That's it - no expressions, no database objects names (tables, columns, aliases, stored procedures, ...), just a literal values.